# "Error displaying advert - Access is denied" while using CVS in command prompt

Tags: cvs, tortoisecvs

I am very inexperienced with CVS and indeed coding in general. Please bear this in mind!

I am trying to access the logs for CVS repositories on SourceForge. In order to do this I am inputting a command into PowerShell that looks something like this:

```
cvs -d:pserver:anonymous@<programname>.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/<programname> login
```

I am able to successfully log in as an anonymous user and access the repository, but every time I enter a command I get a pop-up saying "Error displaying advert - Access is denied".

After clicking "Okay" on this message, the command runs just as it would normally.

This error only occurs when accessing CVS repositories.

Does anybody have any idea what this means, and how to prevent it from happening?

The command prompt I am using is Windows PowerShell on Windows 10 OS. My CVS client is Tortoise CVS.

Comment: Seems a [known bug in TortoiseCVS](https://sourceforge.net/p/tortoisecvs/bugs/1389/). Try a different CVS client.

Comment: I've tried switching to SmartCVS and am having the same problem.

Comment: It's not you. It's cvs. I've recently run into the same problem. Trying to figure it out ....

Comment: Same problem for me. Especially annoying when building several projects, and the popup appears 20-30 times. Not a solution, only a workaround I could find out: I wrote a small Java application to verify every second whether the popup is displayed, and send it an Enter keystroke using a small utility. Not an elegant way of solving the problem, but the only way I could find to avoid the clicks at every build process.

Answer (score 0):

If you see in at

https://github.com/yath/cvsnt/blob/master/windows-NT/win32.cpp (around win32 init, line 400)

You will see, that the reason for this error is the situation, that cvsnt will write a advertising of March Hare onto your desktop. They try to find a window resource to attach a message box for the "advert", an message which shows you "Please buy CVS server..."

This message pops and then after 1 day and 8 hours it pops again, or, if you had worked on the commandline it was shown on the console.

The message is not critical.

Workaround:

If you work with Toitoise or other warppers e.g. powershell it is a good practice to do a fake cvs commandline action without the wrapper on a console and then the message does not appear for 36 hours...

BTW: This "looking for the top window" may be suppressed by windows due to some security rules, cause this is very dangerous way to occupy handles for a message box (but I'm not shure).

Answer (score 0):

The community edition of TortosieCVS is over 7 years old and no longer maintained.

The commercial edition works 'out of the box', and there are no adverts:
https://www.march-hare.com/cvspro/#downcvs

Torsten has previously written to the TortoiseCVS mailing list that the community edition of TortoiseCVS is no longer being maintained:
https://sourceforge.net/p/tortoisecvs/mailman/message/34744873/

Also the main download page has the same info:
http://www.tortoisecvs.org/download.shtml

Please download the trial version of the commercial edition (CVS Suite 2009R2) from our web site of the latest release just a few weeks old, and if you experience a problem, please contact our free pre-sales technical support team: sales@march-hare.com -

March Hare Software continue to develop CVSNT (which is what does the actual client/server connection in TortoiseCVS, as well as the 'checkout' and 'commit' etc. etc.) and we also continue to develop TortoiseCVS including Windows 8 and 10 support.

To upgrade, uninstall all of : CVS, CVSNT, TortoiseCVS, TortoiseOverlays, WinCVS, WinMerge; then reboot and install CVS Suite 2009R2 Trial. Your existing settings will be preserved. CVS Suite works best with CVS Suite Server, but will mostly work with older CVS servers too.